# Javascript, for-loop, not carrying the value

Tags: javascript, for-loop, decrement

The form that fetches the value:

```
<input name="validatecard" type="text" id="myCardNumber"> 
<input onclick="isLuhn()" type="button" value="Check Credit Card" />
```

The Javavascript:

```
function isLuhn(cardnumber) {
var number_element = document.getElementById('myCardNumber');
var cardnumber = number_element.value;

e= '';
i= '';
var sum1 = 0;
var sum2 = 0;
for(var len = cardnumber.length, i = len - 1; i >= 0;  i -=2){
sum1 = sum1 + (+cardnumber[i]);

for (var len2 = cardnumber.length, e = len2 - 1; e > 0; e -=2){
sum2 = sum2 + (+cardnumber[e]);
}}}
```

So right now this is almost working, it is iterating over the cardnumber variable and sum1 and sum2 accepts values. But I am still iterating over the relative length of the variable cardnumber, not the values within it. Is this what the

```
(+cardnumber[i]);
```

should do?

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i = cardnumber.length; i > 0;  i -=2){

for (e = cardnumber.length; e > 0; e -=2){
```

Since your `for` loops are reversed , loop conditions are `i > 0` and `e > 0` otherwise they're never executed

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#For_loop

> The syntax of the JavaScript for loop is as follows:
>
> for (initial; condition; loop statement) {
>        /*
>        statements will be executed every time
>        the for{} loop cycles, **while the
>        condition is satisfied**    */
>   }

Beside to load the `i-th` digit of your number you should do like so:

```
for(var len = cardnumber.length, i = len - 1; i >= 0;  i -=2){
    sum1 = sum1 * cardnumber[i];
```

Note that

1. indexes of a string are `0..n-1` and not `1..n`
2. loop has to enter also when `i = 0` so that the for condition must be true for `i >= 0`

No need to have a parseInt. Since multiplying assumes numbers, Javascript makes your `i-th` character a number.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks, I lost my cool and thus my brains on that one. The actual problem I have is the one I wrote in the update, to get the iteration to work on the actual numbers in cardnumber, not the length of cardnumber. I have been working with this for a few too many hours without finding answers. Is parseInt a helper here? charAt?

Comment: Thanks for very valuable input so far. Got time for a last(hopefully) follow-up? :)